# Group by month and divide the average of one column by the average of the other?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns A and B. I want to divide the mean of A by the mean of B.

```
df['Test']= df.groupby('Month').apply(lambda x: df['A'].mean().astype(float)/df['B'].mean().astype(float))
```

Help me, where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is likely that you define your lambda with `x` as parameter but then use `df`. It should rather be:

```
df.groupby('Month').apply(lambda x: x['A'].mean()/x['B'].mean())
```

*NB. converting to float after computing the mean makes little sense, should you convert **before**?*

You can use instead:

```
g = df.groupby('Month')
out = g['A'].mean()/g['B'].mean()
```

or for a transformation:

```
g = df.groupby('Month')
df['Test'] = g['A'].transform('mean')/g['B'].transform('mean')
```